# preencher combobox de municipio de acordo com o estado selecionado em Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Bom dia,

Possuo uma `combobox` de município que é carregada com os municípios de acordo com o estado selecionado, estou trazendo os dados de uma API feita em C# da seguinte forma:

```
$http.post('views/sistema/sistemas/service.aspx/Municipio', {
    estado: form.estado || ''
    }).then(function (success) {
        let data = JSON.parse(success.data.d);
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        $scope.municipioDestino.aaData = data.map(it => {
            return {
                municipio: it.Municipio
            };
        });
    }, function (error) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
});
```

porem é retornado o erro:

> angular.js:13236 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SistemaController' is not a function, got undefined

O que ha de errado?

Comment: postei errado, ja removi...

Comment: Bom, pelo jeito está faltando código aí, mas pelo erro  o problema está neste **SistemaController**, talvez a sintaxe esteja errada, pois está informando que o mesmo não é uma função e está como indefinido.